# Misaligned paragraph (after subsubsection)

Tags: spacing, lyx, sections-paragraphs

I'm new to LaTeX & LyX. I find that in LyX, when I have a "subsubsection" then "standard" block of text, it looks like

[image]

where the immediate line after the subsubsection is aligned with the header while following paragraphs are not. Why is that? How do I align them?

Comment: Please provide the code that produced the above graphic. That way it is easier to assess the problem and how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I solved this by going `Document > Settings > Text Layout`. Select Vertical Space instead of Indentation

[image]

Answer (score 4):

that is the default behavior of new paragraphs which have an indented first line. Put

- `\noindent` before that line
- add `%` to the empty line before that paragraphs which should'nt be indented the first line
- set `\parindent=0pt` and `\parskip=0.5\normalbaselineskip plus0.3ex minus 0.2ex` into the preamble
- or choose `parskip=half` into the optional argument of the documentclass when using a KOMA class